# Using class in a link and stylesheet?

Tags: css, class, html, hyperlink

Hi i'm trying to design a class object

```
<a href="url here" class="gallery">View Photos</a>
```

and here is my css

```
.gallery
{
width:60px;
background-color: #09a2e9;  
padding:5px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Function Pro Light;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
}

a.gallery:link {
font-family: Function Pro Light;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
}
```

What i'm trying to go for is something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue6sM.jpg

but my css isn't working. How do i fix this.

The div stretches full width, and i don't want it to stretch at all and i don't want to have too set a width and height.

Also how do i get it to center itself without adding the

```
<center> </center>
```

tags

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in modern browsers (i.e. not IE7 or below)

```
.gallery
{
  /* force the element to keep to it's content */
  display: inline-block;
  /* centering */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* */
  background-color: #09a2e9;  
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Function Pro Light;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: They can also add ```text-decoration:none;``` if they want to remove the underline as in the image that is referenced in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
a.gallery{
width:60px;
background-color: #09a2e9;  
padding:5px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Function Pro Light;
color:#fff;
font-size:30px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

a.gallery:link {
font-family: Function Pro Light;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can also get a font from [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) if you need one.

To center: `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers are close, but this should do it.

For centering, you cannot do `margin: 0 auto` for an `inline` or `inline-block` element. Only `block` level elements will center this way (if they have a set width). You'll need to place the button/link element inside of a block level element (like a `div` or a `p`) and then set `text-align: center` on that parent element.

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" class="gallery">My Button</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  background-color: #09a2e9;  
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Function Pro Light", Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzTnv/
Browser Support for border radius: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius